# Unescaping Unicode chars in PHP strings

Tags: php, regex, unicode

If a user types their password in the login form on my site as **Password§1234**, the corresponding $_POST variable will contain the string **Password\xc2\xa71234**. This string is then hashed and compared with the password hash already in the database.

This wouldn't ordinarily be a problem because this escaping would occur both at the signup and login stages and would therefore still match the hash in the database. However, my site allows logins through a desktop API and this API interprets the string correctly without escaped characters before hashing. Consequently the desktop hash doesn't match and the user therefore cannot login.

I know there are a lot of threads on this topic, however I could not find any solutions that dealt with my problem, which may be something to do with the fact that the syntax is \xc2\xa7 rather than U+00A7.

The easiest solution of course would be to escape it on the desktop but I would much rather fix the problem than make everything equally incorrect. It's also easier to update the server than ship multiple app updates out.

Comment: Please, show result of var_dump of POST item.

Comment: The result of var_dump is **string(13) "PasswordÂ§1234"**.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can just use `utf8_encode($password)`. [Sample here](http://codepad.org/u1XqOj3t)

Comment: \xc2\xa7 - it's one UTF character. And this string is UTF already: http://codepad.org/GSUuBwrN

Comment: @Travesty3 The output of the string in that code sample is incorrect for me. It's displaying as **PasswordÂ§1234**.

Comment: @sectus The string I posted above was the output from error_log. I tried echoing the string and ended up with PasswordÂ§1234.